# ms access form vba visible last x records

Tags: vba, ms-access

Is it possible in a continuous form to add a button and hide all records except the last 20 records?

Prefer by NewDate.

```
SELECT TypeID,
   tblID.CodeID,
   APrice AS 1,
   Null AS 2,
   ADate AS NewDate
FROM tblA 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN tblID 
       ON tblID.TypeID = tblA.TypeID

UNION ALL

SELECT TypeID,
   tblID.CodeID,
   NULL AS 1,
   MPrice AS 2,
   MDate AS NewDate
FROM tblM
       LEFT OUTER JOIN tblID 
       ON tblID.TypeID = tblM.TypeID

ORDER BY NewDate;
```

The use of TOP is a solution.

Comment: Yes. it's possible. Since you didn't provide any code, all I can tell you is to redefine the recordsource property for the form with a query that provides the recordset you desire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your table were Orders, and you only wanted to see the fields:
Order ID, Employee ID, Customer ID, Oder Date

You could sort by ID in Descending order and ask for the top (x) records.

```
SELECT  TOP 10 [Order ID], [Employee ID], [Customer ID], [Order Date] FROM Orders ORDER BY [Order ID] DESC;
```

Once you've selected the records you want you could then sort the records by date.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
   Me.OrderBy = "Order Date DESC"         ' Sort by descending date.
   Me.OrderByOn = True                    ' Apply the sort order.
End Sub
```

Comment: Is it possible to use TOP in the form at the [NewDate] Control Source Property and not apply it in the query?

Comment: As in a Parameter Query or as in Apply Filter? "Top" is a SQL command, so at some point a query must be involved.

Comment: Unless you mean storing the SQL with the form and not saved as a query where you could do something like toggling the record source such as; Me.RecourdSource = "SELECT TOP 20 [Order ID], [Employee ID], [Customer ID], [Order Date] FROM Orders ORDER BY [Order ID] DESC;"